# Syncing my iMac and Macbook Pro - All Data and Files

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, imac

If I'm wanting to sync my iMac and my MacBook Pro so that I don't have to connect it every time or back it up through time machine what would be the best way? I want a true sync. So If I save something on the iMac it populates on the MacBook Pro and vice versa.

Would that be through a cloud structured database? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance of course!

Comment: There are a bunch of ways that you can do this.  I've got a way using Unison that I use, but to help people answer: Do you want to sync just your data?  Do you want to sync apps?  What about preferences? How much data do you want to keep in sync? (e.g. If you want to sync a few gigs of documents, something like Dropbox is great, but syncing 200GB of docs and preferences would not work well)

Comment: Yes, I could have been more clear. I'm looking to sync every single thing. Preferences, docs, apps, desktop background...you name it, I'm looking to sync it. I'm wanting them to stay identical so I don't have to keep doing the same thing twice.